# Why is my previous history command in the terminal overwriting other text?

Tags: linux, text

Here is my .bashrc config for ps1 i believe ive done it correctly but any time i press up for a previous command it gets all jumbled up. I can write long lines of commands without it wrapping only the "previous history" is giving me trouble.

```
PS1='\[\e[38;5;9m[\]\[\e[38;5;214m\u\]\[\e[38;5;41m@\]\[\e[38;5;4m\h\] \[\e[38;5;9m\W]\]\[\e[38;5;254m\$ \]'
```

Answer (score 0):

solved moved the actual text I wanted to the outside of the open and closed brackets like so:

```
PS1='\[\e[38;5;9m\][\[\e[38;5;214m\]\u\[\e[38;5;41m\]@\[\e[38;5;4m\]\h \[\e[38;5;9m\]\W]\[\e[38;5;254m\]\$ '
```