# What is wrong with my terminal? Backspace won't delete everything on the terminal line

Tags: linux, centos, terminal

In my Centos linux terminal, if I press up on the arrow keys to bring up a previous command, specifically a long one, and then try to delete it using backspace, it won't delete the entire command. I have to use ctrl+c to bring up another line since I can't delete it. The thing I noticed is if I delete as much as I can on the line and enter a valid command, it still runs it.

For example, say I bring up a previous command and now my terminal line looks like

```
  [user@centos]$ sudo mount -t iso9660 -o loop nameoffile.iso /mnt/mntpnt
```

I start "backspacing" but can't delete everything so now it's just

```
  [user@centos]$ sudo mount
```

but if I type a command such as pwd

```
  [user@centos]$ sudo mountpwd
```

it will execute the command and list my current directory.

Comment: Broken `PS1` or `PROMPT_COMMAND`, or any speciel character in history.

Comment: This is https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/317734/ , https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/446118/ , et al. again.